# Is it possible to access a solver propertiese through Pycaffe?

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

Is it possible to read and access the solver properties in `Pycaffe`?
I need to use some of the information stored in the solver file, but apparently the solver object which is created using

```
import caffe  
solver = caffe.get_solver(solver_path)
```

is of no use in this case.  Is there any other way to get around this problem?

Comment: what parameters do you need to access?

Comment: @Basically, I want to automate as much as I can. I mean, if a training loop needs to know about, batch_size, test_iter, max_iter, etc, they all would be fetched programmatically. currently some can be accessed from solver object itself, but nearly all others cant. I need such information both for logging and training/testing purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find what I was after using solver object and I ended up writing a quick function to get around this issue:

```
def retrieve_field(solver_path, field=None):
    '''
    Returns a specific solver parameter value using the specified field  
    or the whole content of the solver file, when no field is provided.

    returns: 
    a string, as a field value or the whole content as list
    '''
    lines = []
    field_segments = []
    with open(solver_path, 'r') as file:
        for line in file: 
            line = line.strip()
            lines.append(line)
            field_segments = line.split(':')
            if (field_segments[0] == field):
                #if that line contains # marks (for comments)
                if('#' in field_segments[-1]):
                    idx = field_segments[-1].index('#')
                    return field_segments[-1][0:idx]
                else:
                    return field_segments[-1]

    return lines
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good way to tackle this task. You should use caffe_pb2.py to parse the solver.

Comment: @Shai, I didn't know of any other ways, what is that? could you explain on that a bit more?

Comment: @Shai: Thanks alot, I'll look into it :)